# Recovery actions PHM FC can provide in adaptive AUTOSAR

Tags: autosar

I am working on developing pHM(platform health management) FC for adaptive AUTOSAR stack.
From requirements, it not very cleary that what kind of recovery action we can implement failure in application's execution.

I need some clarity,
What kind of recovery actions i can implement to overcome application or platform failure.

Currently,  I have implemented fucntional group state change, as a recovery.

Any other option which i can implement?